# Using a token in url that has nothing to do with logging in still tries to log user in

Tags: meteor, angular-ui-router, meteor-accounts, angular-meteor

So I've got an angular-meteor app where I want to perform an action that requires a token.

I'm able to send the email with the proper url, and in browsers I don't use for development (Firefox/Safari) everything works *perfectly*.

However, my chrome browser typically has me logged in as an admin for local development and when I log myself out to test this url on chrome, it consistently tries to log me in using this token! My steps are,

1. open new tab
2. paste url
3. hit enter

I keep getting this error: **Error logging in with token: Error: You've been logged out by the server. Please log in again. [403]**

And being redirected to my login page.

What really confuses me, is if I re-paste the url into the address bar (this is all in the same exact tab as the three steps above) and hit enter, everything works fine.

What in the wide-wide world of sports is going on? I don't even know what code to paste here because to be honest, everything is working perfectly fine outside of the quirk of logging out as an admin and then opening a brand new tab to visit the url.

Is there some sort of built-in feature that can recognize a token and automatically tries to parse it for logging in? Is there some session data that isn't cleared when you logout in meteor?

I'm seriously driven up the wall because I can't find examples of people using tokens for anything other than auto-logging in.

Comment: Could you try same steps in Chrome, but on #2 step — remove token from the URL before hitting `Enter`.

Comment: @Styx I tried and I get the very same **[403]** error that appears above.